How to hide my favorite workshop items?
I just found that my favorite workshop items are public even if I set my profile private. They can be seen even without a steam login.
Is there a way to hide them? I don't want other people to see what have I set favorite in the workshop.

As of 17th of May 2024, there's no way to hide your favorite workshop items.
Source: https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/864973032839821447/
Plus the privacy settings only say it's per item, not a global setting, and it doesn't apply to workshop items you favorite because on the workshop page you only get a "Favorite" button with no option to make it private.


Thank you!! Never expected that this could be a ten year plus discussion :( I am also quite confusing for that 'per-item' saying, it's good to know that i am not alone :D
